# Angular can't load module for prerender.js/phantom.js only for pproduction

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, yeoman-generator-angular, prerender

Website runs without any problems in production (files minified and concatenated), but when a page is sent to prerender.js or phantom.js for snapshot generation, I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.
>
> https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:4
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:3 in d
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:4 in m
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:4 in db
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:3 in g
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:3 in ea
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:3 in da
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:8
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:2 in j
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:2 in fireWith
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:2 in ready
>   https://www.mydomain.io/app/vendor.7240ef6a.js:1 in g

I have to files: vendor.js and app.js. I have exactly the same structure on my another project (just the files are different) and it works well with the same prerender.js server.

I managed to track the problem down to jquery.js. But I get stuck at that point. Seems like prerender/phanatom.js load files in different way. A also used `window.prerenderReady = true/false` to no avail.

I am using [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) with Angular v1.5.8 and jQuery v2.2.4

In index.html jquery is included before angular. I wonder if there are any ways to get more detailed information on what causes the problem.

Comment: Is it just phantom js or other browsers as well? sounds like a problem with dependency injection.  Try to add `ng-strict-di` on the element with `ng-app` i.e. `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>`

Comment: Did you manage to find out a solution for this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: Same issue here. How did you fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before if your files are being loaded in the `<body>`. Loading scripts in the `<body>` makes them load asynchronously where it's possible that the scripts load in the incorrect order. Most newer browsers handle that nicely but PhantomJS (v2.1.1) will execute the script as soon as it's loaded, no matter the ordering.

I'd suggest trying to load those scripts in the `<head>`.

Comment: I tried this workaround, but it did not work out. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you send us an email at support@prerender.io with your website? We can test your site and figure out what the issue might be

Comment: @Prerender.io did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: We use Chrome for our rendering now at Prerender.io and Chrome fixes the issue completely.